# Enum.Parse always failing

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to parse a String and convert it as an Enum. I can't use Dictionaries in this area of the code so I use Enum.Parse(). However it always fails, even though the string being passed should definitively match an enum. Here's the C# code:

```
hp.ItemSubType.Add((ItemSubtype)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemSubtype), subTypeString));
```

And this is the enum definition:

```
public enum ItemSubtype
    {
        ADSComputer,
        // Bunch of values
        CPU
    }
```

Now even when the value of `subTypeString`is, for instance, "CPU", it won't match anything in the enum . Do we **have** to use annotations for this?

Comment: Do you have an exception message? As it is I can't see any obvious problem.

Comment: Looks good to me: (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), enumString);

Comment: A hard to spot whitespace perhaps?

Comment: Looks fine, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You might want to split your code out into a seperate line for each method call, so you can see where it falls over, also can you show us what hp is?

Comment: Remember that by default, `Enum.Parse` is case sensitive. Maybe it's a case issue?

Comment: What type does the Add method expect?

Comment: To sum up all the questions above: please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: According to the documentation Enum.Parse is case sensitive, make sure the string contains CPU and not cpu.

Comment: I have tested this code is working --  var subTypeString = "CPU";
       var test = Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemSubtype), subTypeString); --
but If change change CPU to ItemSubtype.CPU i get a crash!

Comment: For me the parse is still functional.  Try: ItemSubtype st = (ItemSubtype)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemSubtype), "CPU");  Could you pls post the rest of your code. What is "hp"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I write this code

```
namespace N
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            X value1 = (X)Enum.Parse(typeof(X), "CPU");
            X value2;
            Enum.TryParse("CPU", out value2);
            Console.WriteLine(value1);
            Console.WriteLine(value2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public enum X
    {
        CPU
    }
}
```

and test it. Guess what, everything works as expected. So no, you don't need to use annotations.

Comment: I'm flagging this as the answer because the code is correct. However the root cause was that the ItemSubType property wasn't properly instanced in the constructor. So the problem did lie somewhere else than in the parsing.

Comment: @Astaar, divide and conquer.

Comment: Also, [`select` Isn't Broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26).

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess and a hint: C# is case sensitive, so `Cpu` is not the same as `CPU`. Also, you can use the generic [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) which makes the code more readable and also enables to handle invalid input:

```
ItemSubtype itemType;
bool canParse = Enum.TryParse<ItemSubtype>("cpu", out itemType);  // false
if(canParse)
{
    hp.ItemSubType.Add(itemType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the add and not in parsing I have tested the parsing

```
var subTypeString = "CPU"; var test = Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemSubtype), subTypeString);
```

Check your collection type(hp.ItemSubType) it must have the same type of the Enum!